# Is this GCC optimization incorrect?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, assembly, floating-point

I have a functor which takes a value, casts it to double, takes the log and casts the value back to the original type. For the purpose of this question, the original and output type is float. Here is the original C++ code:

```
return static_cast< TOutput >( std::log( static_cast< double >( A ) ) )
```

When I compile in debug mode, everything goes as expected and GCC calls the underlying `log` function:

```
  51:/myfile.h ****     return static_cast< TOutput >( std::log( static_cast< double >( A ) ) );
 219133                 .loc 112 51 0
 219134 0010 488B45F0     movq  -16(%rbp), %rax # A, tmp64
 219135 0014 F30F1000     movss (%rax), %xmm0 # *A_1(D), D.237346
 219136 0018 0F14C0       unpcklps  %xmm0, %xmm0  # D.237346, D.237346
 219137 001b 0F5AC0       cvtps2pd  %xmm0, %xmm0  # D.237346, D.237347
 219138 001e E8000000     call  log #
 219138      00
 219139 0023 660F14C0     unpcklpd  %xmm0, %xmm0  # D.237347
 219140 0027 660F5AC0     cvtpd2ps  %xmm0, %xmm0  # D.237347, D.237346
 219141 002b F30F1145     movss %xmm0, -20(%rbp)  # D.237346, %sfp
 219141      EC
 219142 0030 8B45EC       movl  -20(%rbp), %eax # %sfp, <retval>
```

However, when I turn optimizations on (-O2 -ggdb3 -DNDEBUG), it calls the `logf` (???) function:

```
  51:/myfile.h ****     return static_cast< TOutput >( std::log( static_cast< double >( A ) ) );
 145171                 .loc 64 51 0
 145172 01a0 F30F1004     movss (%rdx,%rax,4), %xmm0  # MEM[(const float &)_84], MEM[(const float &)_84]
 145172      82         
 145173 01a5 E8000000     call  logf  #
```

It gives a different output. Is this normal? Am I doing anything wrong? It seems to me that GCC is taking a very liberal interpretation of my code, which I wouldn't expect in the absence of the `-ffast-math` option.

Comment: Can you add a minimal amount of C++ code that corresponds to the test case?

Comment: Assuming TOutput is a template parameter: what happens if you just replace it with float? Just a curiosity.

Comment: Writing a simple test case might be a bit difficult because if gcc knows the input value at compilation time it will probably optimize the whole computation away. But I will try.

Comment: [here](http://goo.gl/P4ba3r) it is with -O2 and logf call, and [here](http://goo.gl/YBv41z) is the same with -O0 and log.

Comment: @frymode: You forgot to `return` from that templated function.

Comment: Have you messed around with the optimization options? For C code, gcc enables a lot of buggy/nonsensical math optimizations by default in the "gnu89", "gnu99", etc. profiles but turns them off if you use `-std=c99`, etc. I don't know what the analogous behavior for C++ is, though.

Comment: @R.. I just tried explicitly selecting C++03, didn't change anything: http://goo.gl/

Comment: Perhaps try an equivalent C test program with `-std=c99`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is a borderline optimization to transform the conversion to `float` of an application of the double-precision `log` to a float to an application of the single-precision `log`, but it can be argued to be acceptable.

Assuming that `logf` is correctly rounded and that the double-precision `log` is also correctly rounded or at least faithfully-rounded, the two computations will rarely differ. They can differ (for some rare inputs) because of [double-rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) (in which “double” means “twice” and does not refer to the type). Double-rounding is statistically all the less significant that there are additional digits in the intermediate type's significand compared to the final type's significand (and this statistical argument is slightly rubbish from a mathematical point of view, but it “works in practice” for functions that have not been designed to be counter-examples). For didactic reasons, people (or Wikipedia) explain it with one or two extra digits of precision, but when you have 53 - 24 = 29 extra binary digits, it can be expected to happen as rarely as once in 2<sup>29</sup>.

I am surprised by the optimization, and I would disturbed by it if I had written the code myself for an exhaustive search of double-rounding problems with `log`, but considering that the C++ standard does not mandate any level of accuracy from `std::log`, it is possible to consider it “not a bug”.

---

If, instead of `log`, we had been talking of one of the basic operations (such as `*`), then the transformation would have been incorrect, for a compiler that claims to provide IEEE 754 semantics, when it introduces visible changes. For a basic operation, the accuracy is specified indirectly by IEEE 754, and the specification leaves no room for variations.

It so happens that for the basic operations, there cannot be a visible change when `floatOP(flx,fly)` replaces `(float)doubleOP((double)flx, (double)fly)` (this [thesis](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/web/Research/Theses/figueroa_sam.pdf) demonstrates this in chapter 6) , but there can be visible differences when the types are `double` and `long double`. This exact bug was [recently fixed](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.cvs/167711) in Clang by Stephen Canon.

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing such a perfect answer.

Comment: I would put this solidly in the category of "optimizations that might be allowed by the standard, but are detrimental to quality of life for users", especially when applied to source expressions that so clearly are intended to evaluate in the wider type.  It hurts predictability, and leads to more users who believe that floating-point is black magic.  This is roughly akin to reassociating a product, which I definitely wouldn't tolerate outside of fast-math.

Comment: And thanks for reminding me that I transposed your name.  Feel free to keep rubbing it in.

Comment: @StephenCanon I considered attributing the Clang patch to Steven Canon.

Comment: This really terrifies me.

Comment: I wish languages and libraries would allow programmers to indicate what sort of precision they need.  For many kinds of calculations, computing a result accurate to 24 significant bits might take twice as long as computing one that's only accurate to 20; in some cases that would be time well spent, but in other cases the less accurate results would be just as useful as more accurate results would be, so switching to the faster computation would be a "win".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this optimisation is incorrect.  `log` and `logf` are only required to be faithfully-rounded, so one could have

```
logf(4) = 0x1.62e42p+0
log(4)  = 0x1.62e42fefa39efp+0
```

Changing the upconversion, `log`, and downconversion to a `logf` call may give incorrect results.

Pascal Cuoq's answer correctly points out that, if `logf` is correctly-rounded and `log` isn't garbage, then the results probably won't differ.  However, `logf` on my platform is *not* correctly-rounded:

```
logf(0x1.306p-138)       = -0x1.7decc8p+6
(float)log(0x1.306p-138) = -0x1.7decc6p+6
mpfr_log(0x1.306p-138)   = -0x1.7decc6ff8a7a4a4450e9p+6
```

Thankfully, I'm unable to reproduce this "optimisation" with my gcc.

Comment: Well, the compilation platform comprises the standard libraries and the compiler. So the compiler could be applying crazy-wrong optimizations knowing that the math library provides a correctly-rounded `logf`. Joking aside, it is becoming urgent to write the “check for double-rounding issues in a `float(float)` function” program that I was already tempted to write in another discussion with aka.nice. As aka.nice said, it is not completely impossible there are interesting arguments to discover.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: It's calling `logf`, which is a function that has weak linkage in glibc.  Even if glibc provided a correctly-rounded `logf` on your platform, I can drop in a correct faithfully-but-not-correctly-rounded `logf`.  I can even do that in a different translation unit.  This "optimisation" breaks programs.

Comment: If you consider this a bug, then you should file a report against all GCC versions, which will transform `lv1 = lv2;` to `memcpy(&lv1, &lv2, …);` for sufficiently large values of `sizeof lv2`. This transformation is incorrect because `lv1 = lv2;` is defined when `lv1` and `lv2` refer to the exact same location in memory, whereas `memcpy` needs not function in this case (but GCC comes with a `memcpy` that, indeed, does function in this case).

Comment: I would probably consider this to be a bug if I could reproduce it.  But I can't.  I don't really care about the `memcpy` thing; I think `memcpy` was specified incorrectly.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Using `memcpy` in that situation seems icky; I would think a memcpy-ish function which operated on the largest type which could be accessed with the alignment of lv1 and lv2 would be much better.  If the compiler knows how lv1 and lv2 are aligned, why require a memcpy() function to figure it out at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried an equivalent C program:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


static double dostuff(float in)
{
  return log(in);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  float in = strtof(argv[1], NULL);
  float out = dostuff(in);
  printf("%f\n", out);
  return 0;
}
```

And found that **gcc does not use logf even when using -Ofast**. The only thing `-Ofast` enables is `__log_finite()` to be used. However, changing the return type of `dostuff()` to `float` *does* enable this optimization.

Comment: Well, returning double (your prog) from the function vs. returning float (the OP's C++) seems to be and to make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have any concern about the different output.  If you cast a float value to a double and then back to a float value; you can get a different value; therefore the different value that you get from casting a float to a double value, performing the log operation and then casting down the result back to a float is not better than the value that you get by calling directly the logf function.

If you have any concern about the precision of the operation, then you shouldn't use the float type at all and all your mathematical values should be double all the way.

By using the float type, you signal the compilator that you don't have any special attention to the final precision of your mathematical operations beyond that of the one provided by the float type.  Put in other words, when you do some mathematical operations with real numbers (numbers other than integers), the precision can only either remains the same or decrease; it can never increase; therefore, if you start with a float type, you cannot increase your precision beyond that type.